# How to use ListBox.ListIndex

Tags: excel, vba

I am going through a single select list box, to determine which series to select. The previous developer on this did the following:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox4.ListCount - 1
   If ListBox4.Selected(i) Then
      Series_Msg = Series_Msg & ListBox4.List(i) & vbNewLine
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i + 1).Select

      'other commands

  Next i
```

In an attempt to clean up his code, i tried to do something like the following:

```
   If ListBox4.ListIndex <> -1 then

       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ListBox4.ListIndex + 1).Select
```

But i get an object required error. I tried declaring i as an object and assigning it the ListIndex value but that didn't work.

Can anyone suggest how i can do this without the loop? I can't believe that this loop is necessary.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Russ

Comment: Do `Debug.Print ActiveChart.Name`. Do you get an error on that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've got the chart properly selected:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

If ListBox4.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    Series_Msg = Series_Msg & ListBox4.List(ListBox4.ListIndex, 0)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ListBox4.ListIndex + 1).Select
End If
```

Comment: I noticed the same thing. I always prefer to use an object variable instead of ActiveChart, so I have more explicit and permanent control of the object. `ActiveChart` is prone to that sort of error :)

Answer (score 0):

Trye using:
`ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ListBox4.List(ListBox4.ListIndex)).Select`

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me, provided there is an `ActiveChart`. Add some handling to ensure that ActiveChart is not Nothing. Otherwise, you will get that error, `Object Variable or With Block not set`.

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ListBox1.AddItem "First"
    ListBox1.AddItem "Second"
    ListBox1.AddItem "Third"
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
Dim i As Integer

If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then 
    MsgBox "There is no ActiveChart!"
    Exit Sub
End If

i = ListBox1.ListIndex + 1

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Select
'Alternatively, you can ignore "i" and just use ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ListBox1.ListIndex+1).Select

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

Comment: I had tried setting i = ListBox4.ListIndex and using that as the index, but i got the object error as well.

I may want to mention that this is in the ListBox4_Click event.

The ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ListBox4.List(ListBox4.ListIndex)).Select seems to have worked!

Thanks to all!

Comment: You were getting the error with `i` if I recall because you had dimensioned it as an object and were not setting it. If you dimension it as integer/long, this should work (and it does work, I verify) because `ListBox1.ListIndex+1` **is** an integer/long numeric data. Also, any reason you're using the default `_Click` event rather than the `_AfterUpdate` event?

Comment: And, as I and others have mentioned, you are getting the error because some variable is not properly set, or more likely because `ActiveChart` is Nothing at the time the code executes.  You need to debug for `ActiveChart` to make sure that is set properly. I suspect that will solve your problem.

Comment: I am pretty new to using the various events, like Click. After clicking an item in a ListBox, is it preferred to have the code called in the _AfterUpdate?

Comment: In general, the Click event fires whenever a control receives a 
mouse click, while the AfterUpdate event fires when the control's value is updated.  In a listbox, if you click and hold the mouse button down you can move between the different items without releasing the mouse button, this way the user could conceivably move the cursor while the _Click event is trying to fire, which could cause errors maybe. The _AfterUpdate event seems more likely to capture the user's final selection.

Comment: I think i'll try that. Based on the users selection in the ListBox4, i display attributes of the Series selected, by selecting items in other ListBoxs on the userform. I'll give that a try also. Thanks!

Comment: CHeers! Consider upvoting if my suggestions have been helpful to you